# How to exclude symbols/character with RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

The problem is not quite as simple as the title says.
I have text where `#` and `$` are inside words.
There are never adjacent `#`'s or `$`'s but there can be more than one in a word.

Example: `Sta#ck ov#er$flow.`

I want to match every character in the text except `#` and `$` when they are at the beginning or the end of a word.

String in: `#Sta#ck ov$er#flow`

Desired match: `Sta#ck ov$er#flow`

String in: `Sta$ck# +$= $overflo#w`

Desired match: `Sta$ck += overflo#w`

This is close to doing the job:

```
[^#\$]([^#\$\s\W]+[#\$]?[^#\$\s\W])*
```

Examples of where it fails:

String in: #a$a#a

Match: aaa (but I want a$a#a)

String in: #aa$a#a

Match: aa$aa (but I want aa$a#a)

Please help me find a RegEx that works.

EDIT: I failed to mention that I'm using this in C#.

Comment: You need to use negative lookahead to prevent matching the character at the end of a word, and negative lookbehind to prevent matching at the beginning. Use in the lookaround to match the word boundary.

Comment: You tagged this with `regex-lookarounds`, why didn't you use it in your attempted solution?

Comment: What you're looking for is not possible with a single regexp match. Your second example asks for a match that filters out characters inside the substring, but regexp match just returns the portion of the original string that matches.

Comment: I tried using regex-lookarounds but had no luck with that. The expression I show is the one I feel gets me the closest. Since it´s not possable to get this done in one expression I would appreciate if someone could help me find a series of expressions that could get this done.

Comment: @Barmar checked your profile and happy to see that you work at one of my favorite sites!  :)

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern matches correct individual characters for all example cases in the question above (need to work on getting them in groups):

```
(?:|\b[#$]+\b|[\w\s+=])
```

[Demo on RegExr](https://regexr.com/4cikp)
*(see "Tools >> Explain" at the bottom of the demo page for overview of the pattern)*

Caveat(s):  Note that I haven't done much testing beyond your samples.  Also, note that this pattern works for PHP/PCRE flavors and not with others, such as JS or Python.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job for me:
`\b[^#\$]*[#$]+[^#\$]?\b[\w\s+]*|\s*[^#\$]*`